# Countif or sumif formula

Tags: countif

I have a guest list for the event and I need to do statistics on RSVP.

```
| Column 1 | Column 2              | Column 3                 |
| (name)   | (if the guest is VIP, | (Count RSVP:             |
|          | has text "VIP")       | 2 - coming with a guest; |
|          |                       | 1 - coming solo;         |
|          |                       | 0 - not attending)       |
|----------|-----------------------|--------------------------|
| Anna     | -                     | 2                        |
| Ben      | VIP                   | 1                        |
| Robert   | VIP                   | 2                        |
| Ken      | VIP                   | 0                        |
| Olga     | -                     | 2                        |
```

So I need to count how many cells in Column 3 have "1" or "2" if they have "VIP" in column 2.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Excel.

Just use `COUNTIFS`:
`=COUNTIFS(B:B,"VIP",C:C,">0")`

[image]